# Saving embedded images in emails with python

Tags: python, image, email

I am trying to grab images in an embedded email. The problem is that the image that i save is unreadable and i can't figure out why.
The email (saved as a file which i load in the beginning of the code):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

Received: by 10.100.120.7 with HTTP; Tue, 18 Oct 2011 10:36:48 -0700 (PDT)

In-Reply-To: <8B4FDE07A4759840B84FD04B4C88100B010135E81D8C@fxildc03.forexmanage.com>

References: <8B4FDE07A4759840B84FD04B4C88100B010135E81D8C@fxildc03.forexmanage.com>

Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 19:36:48 +0200

Delivered-To: s.shpiz@gmail.com

Message-ID: <CAEb-As9XVmciajFAwEaFyF8CE4QG0t-Z5zFDDpMWXLqaBur1sA@mail.gmail.com>

Subject: openme

From: Simeon Shpiz <s.shpiz@gmail.com>

To: me <s.shpiz@gmail.com>

Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=001636c5977303b92404af962ba6



--001636c5977303b92404af962ba6

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001636c5977303b91d04af962ba5



--001636c5977303b91d04af962ba5

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1



****



--001636c5977303b91d04af962ba5

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



<div dir=3D"ltr"><div class=3D"gmail_quote"><div lang=3D"EN-US" link=3D"blu=

e" vlink=3D"purple"><div><p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"font-size:11=

.0pt;color:#1F497D"><img width=3D"15" height=3D"13" src=3D"cid:image003.png=

@01CC8DCD.30A2A7C0"></span><span style=3D"font-size:11.0pt;color:#1F497D"><=

u></u><u></u></span></p>



</div>

</div></div><br></div>



--001636c5977303b91d04af962ba5--

--001636c5977303b92404af962ba6

Content-Type: image/png; name="image003.png"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-ID: <image003.png@01CC8DCD.30A2A7C0>

X-Attachment-Id: 3e79c375acccec3d_0.1



iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAANCAIAAAAWvsgoAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAAO

yAAADsMBrahYpwAAAItJREFUKFNj/P//PwNxgIk4ZWBVQFOBoBsMsGqrqqr6CgYsaNIPHz6EiMjJ

yb19+xbISE9PLy4uBjLQlSLrFBYWBnITExN9fHyADMJulZCQgOgnrFRUVJRYpXAnETb19evXxJr6

4sULiFJ8IfDt2zegii1btmRkZGBRKi8vjxbSwKjJysoCCjISnwYATtwwhahioZoAAAAASUVORK5C

YII=

--001636c5977303b92404af962ba6--
```

The python code i am using:

```
import email
from BeautifulSoup  import BeautifulSoup 

message = email.message_from_file(open(r'C:\shpiz\test\msg\12248'))
cid_list = []
images = []
for part in message.walk():
    if str(part.get_content_type()) == 'text/html':
        soup = BeautifulSoup(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        cid = '<%s>'%soup('img')[0]['src'][4:]
        cid_list.append(cid)

for part in message.walk():
    if part.get('Content-ID') in cid_list :
        images.append((part.get_filename(),part.get_payload(decode=True)))
for name, image in images:
    with open(r'c:\shpiz\test\%s'%name,'w') as f:
        f.write(image)
```

The image saved is unfortunately not good. (No program opens it).

I looked at the original and the new image files with notepad++ and there is a difference- there looks to be a line break my generated copy not present in the original. that's not the only difference though as deleting the line in notepad++ didn't make the image openable. The difference I described can be seen [here](http://i56.tinypic.com/121qrk2.png)

Would appreciate any assistance in finding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing the image in text mode and Python is mangling the line endings. Open it in `wb` mode to write it verbatim.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this lines:

```
for name, image in images:
    with open(r'c:\shpiz\test\%s'%name,'w') as f:
        f.write(image)
```

The file that you create with open is a text file by default. You have to use 'b' together with 'w'. But I don't know if that will solve the entire problem. You might need an specialized reader/writer for graphics files too.

Comment: actually saving with 'wb' instead of 'w+' was the only problem. feel so stupid that i wasted a lot of time to find that out